# Beginner's question) How can I change a variable's type permanently?

Tags: c

I found that

```
char p = 1; 
p = (int)p; 
p = 0x12345678;
```

makes `p` '0x78', because `p`'s type is not changed to `int` at second line, unlike my guess. How can I change `p`'s type itself, without declaring a new variable?

Comment: you can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects have their types forever in the C language. Instead you can often `cast` its value to the another type. In your example `(int)p` value of the `p` is converted to the int, but the original `p` variable will have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a different variable name with the desired type.

```
char p = 1; 
int q = (int)p; 
q = 0x12345678;
```

There isn't another workaround that I am aware of.

As a side note, if you want to ensure portability, be careful when you cast chars to integers or vice versa. The C standard makes a guarantee that e.g. '0' through '9' will be consecutive and increasing, but doesn't make any guarantees as to their values.